# Upload and retrieve image in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, image, laravel, file-upload

I need to save the image for an avatar.

Can anyone give me a simple code to save and retrieve image?

I need to:

- Save image in folder
- Save image name in DB
- Finally retrieve on image tag; I have to do it by Query Builder

**Form:**

```
 <form action="" method="post" role="form" multiple>
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <legend>Form Title</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Your Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="avatar">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
        <a href="{{'/'}}" class="btn btn-primary">back</a>
     </form>
            <img name="youravatar" src="">
        </div>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('pic','avatarController@picshow');

Route::post('pic','avatarController@pic');
```

**Controller:**

I have the `avatarController`, but it is empty because I don't know what to do.

**Database:**

Table name: avatar
Fields: name id, imgsrc, created_at, Updated_at

**Other:**

I found this code but I can't find out anything:

```
 if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
      $file = array('avatar' => Input::file('avatar'));
      $destinationPath = '/'; // upload path
      $extension = Input::file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renaming image
      Input::file('avatar')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
  }
```

Comment: What do you have so far (Controller, Form, Database structure)

Comment: post edited. tnx dude

Comment: Did you check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files ?

Comment: Try setting enctype="multipart/form-data" inside the <form> tag

Comment: yes i seen this but i couldn't do anything almost.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the encrypt attribute in your form

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You can use something similar to this in your controller

```
public function save(Request $request)
{

   $file = $request->file('file');
   // rename your file
   $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
   \Storage::disk('local')->put($name,  \File::get($file));

   return "file saved";
}
```

Yes, you should store the file route in your database as well.

Make sure you are using a consistent path for your images like

Finally you have to create a route to give public access to your image file, like so:

```
Route::get('images/{file}', function ($file) {

    $public_path = public_path();
    $url = $public_path . '/storage/' . $file;

    // file exists ?
    if (Storage::exists($archivo))
    {
       return response()->file($pathToFile);
    }

    //not found ? 
    abort(404);
});
```

Check the docs about [Laravel Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses)

I hope this gives you an Idea of what to do.

Comment: tnx bro, it was usefull

Comment: guys need help again . look up please

Answer (score 0):

Upload Image in laravel 5.4

1. check if request has image

`$request->hasFile('image')`

OR

`$request->file('image')->isValid()`

2. Now Save Image

`$request->inputname->store('folder-name') return image path 'folder name/created image name
 $request->image->store('images')`

3. Check if image exits

`Storage::disk('local')->exists('image name');`

4. Delete Image

`Storage::delete('image');`

This is my code

```
if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid())
            {
                $path = $request->image->store('images');
                if(!empty($path)){
                    $edit = Model::FindOrFail($id);
//                    Delete old image
                    $exists = Storage::disk('local')->exists($edit->image);
                    if($exists){
                        Storage::delete($edit->image);
                    }
                    $edit->image = $path;
                    $edit->save();
                }
            }
```

[Reference](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17nlsJRfgnMtp9R8eeTxy5lhXqcuHmmqqAztlPB2yOmw/edit?usp=sharing)